# Soft ketboard copy service has stopped always at emulator when i select this service

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method, soft-keyboard

when i select my keyboard services from other keyboard services my keyboard will stopped and gives error 1349 and i gettin crayz.

i look sample of soft keyboard example after that i make this copy project and i try again my copy keyboard services always give that mesaage ur keyboard has staooped but when i work soft ketboard orginal services program didnt give any error and this keyboard is used by user.
how i didnt understant everything same two project but one is working one is not why i didnt find any doc abaout it please help

when i change my input cong. to my keyboard services at emulator, devices write that my keyboard has stopped

Comment: You are developing an application? Keyboard crash only in your application? which emulator are you using? which processor it emulates ARM or x86?